# Show that Matrix cannot have $0$ as an eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a Matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$, for which:
$$A^3+2A^2+3A+4I = 0$$
where I is the identity matrix and $0$ the zero matrix. Can $0$ be an eigenvalue of A?

If $0$ were an eigenvector, than the matrix would be singular (determinant would equal $0$), although I don't see how that helps.

Comment: What would it _mean_ to say $0$ _was_ an eigenvalue of $A$?

Comment: Please edit to include your attempt.

Comment: that would imply, its determinant is $0$, so its singular

Comment: Why $A^3$ and $3A^3$ aren't added together?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I corrected it.

Comment: Please edit to include your effort other the question will be closed soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\lambda = 0$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then there exists a $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that
$$
Av = \lambda v = 0
$$
$$
A^2v = \lambda^2 v = 0
$$
$$
A^3v = \lambda^2 v = 0
$$
meaning that
$$
(A^3 + 2A^2 + 3A^3 + 4I)v = 0
$$
$$
A^3v + 2A^2v + 3A^3v + 4Iv = 0
$$$$
0 + 2 \cdot 0 + 3 \cdot 0 + 4v = 0
$$
which can only happen if $v = 0$. Thus $\lambda = 0$ can only be an eigenvalue if the corresponding eigenvector $v = 0$, but by [the definition of an eigenvalue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors)

> In linear algebra, an eigenvector (/ˈaɪɡənˌvɛktər/) or characteristic vector of a linear transformation is a **nonzero vector** that changes at most by a scalar factor when that linear transformation is applied to it

$v = 0$ is not an eigenvector of $A$.